# How to connect entries of a matrix with lines?

Tags: math-mode, decorations

I am looking for a way, to draw lines in a given matrix, that connect two chosen entries. So, for example I would like to use

```
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
```

to initiate the 2x2-matrix with entries 1,2,3,4 and draw a line from 1 to 4 and a line from 3 to 2 within or rather over this matrix.

I would also be interested  in drawing such lines in a matrix, whose entries simply are dots.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what is easy to do with `pstricks` : define as `nodes` the elements in the matrix you want to link, then connect them by a node connection:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %
\usepackage{pst-node} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % To compile with pdflatex --enablewrite18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)

\begin{document}


\[ \begin{pspicture}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \Rnode{a}{1} & \Rnode{b}{2} \\ \Rnode{c}{3} & \Rnode{d}{4}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \psset{linewidth = 0.5pt, nodesep = 0.5pt}
     \ncline{b}{c}\ncline[border = 0.5pt]{a}{d}
\end{pspicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\tikznode[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};}}
\begin{document}
\[ M=
\begin{pmatrix} \tikznode{1}{1} & \tikznode{2}{2} \\ \tikznode{3}{3} & \tikznode{4}{4}\end{pmatrix}\]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[-](1)--(4);\draw[dotted,thick](2)--(3);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4 
\CodeAfter 
  \tikz \draw (1-1) -- (2-2) (1-2) -- (2-1) ;   
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]